# apa6e title page and abstract page not appearing

Tags: titles, apa6

I believe this was working before.   I was trying to get the reference page on a new page and had issued a `\renewcommand` in `apacite`, but now I am having a whole new problem with `apa6e` and I'm not sure if it is related.  Perhaps it is due to an update I may have installed.  The title page and abstract page are missing now.  Perhaps I deleted something and I'm forgetting what it is.

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Paper}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Name}
\authornote{This is an assignment for .}
\abstract{abstract text }
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example

The time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country test
.  According to , the time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\maketitle` (which actually typesets the title page and the abstract):

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Paper}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Name}
\authornote{This is an assignment for .}
\abstract{abstract text }
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example

\maketitle

The time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country test
.  According to , the time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, ok thanks again.  I must have deleted it accidentally.